# How to recursively list all files with timestamps and full path?

Tags: linux, ls

I want to recursively list all files in a given directory, with their full path and their timestamps. Something like this:

```
10:30 Dec 10 2010 /tmp/mydir/myfile
```

I've tried with:

```
find . -type f -exec ls -la {} \;
```

but that doesn't give me the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And another way to do it if your find doesn't support printf

```
find . -type f | xargs ls -al  | awk -v pwd="$PWD" '{ print $(NF-2), $(NF-1) , pwd substr($(NF), 2)}'
```

**Note:** This only works as long as there aren't any spaces in the filenames. Output looks like this:

```
2010-09-29 22:08 /home/nifle/ac.txt
2010-10-04 16:02 /home/nifle/array.sh
2010-10-05 23:32 /home/nifle/b.txt
2010-12-15 16:49 /home/nifle/barcopy/subbar/ghut
2010-12-15 16:48 /home/nifle/bardir/subbar/ghut
2010-09-29 22:16 /home/nifle/foo.gz
2010-09-29 22:16 /home/nifle/foo1.gz
```

Comment: As long as there aren't any spaces in the filenames.

Comment: @Dennis - Ahh, yes you definitely have a point there.

Answer (score 8):

#### Solution 1 (ls)

Run `ls` on each file and filter the result:

```
find "$PWD" -type f -exec ls -la {} \; | cut -d ' ' -f 6-
```

Output:

```
Jun 14 00:02 /tmp/superuser.com/questions/370070/bar
Jun 14 20:24 /tmp/superuser.com/questions/228529/file  with    multiple   spaces
Jan  2  1972 /tmp/superuser.com/questions/228529/old_file
```

#### Solution 2 (-printf)

Use `-printf`:

```
find "$PWD" -type f -printf "%t %p\n"
```

Output:

```
Thu Jun 14 00:02:47.0173429319 2012 /tmp/superuser.com/questions/370070/bar
Thu Jun 14 20:24:16.0947808489 2012 /tmp/superuser.com/questions/228529/file  with    multiple   spaces
Sun Jan  2 03:04:05.0000000000 1972 /tmp/superuser.com/questions/228529/old_file
```

#### Solution 3 (stat)

Run GNU [`stat`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stat-invocation.html) on each file:

```
find "$PWD" -type f -exec stat --format '%y %n' {} \;
```

Output:

```
2016-03-30 04:32:10.034718786 +0300 /etc/passwd
2015-12-21 19:30:07.854470768 +0200 /etc/group
```

---

Tip: if you have GNU find, `\;` can be replaced with `\+`.

Comment: You can replace `$PWD` with `.`.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: the command from the question already uses `.` instead of `$PWD` and it doesn't give him the full path.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246215/how-can-i-list-files-with-their-absolute-path-in-linux) on StackOverflow plays around with one part of your question. In order to get what you want, you could try the following:

```
find $ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_DIR -ls
```

Answer (score 0):

`tree` is a nice alternative:

`tree -fD --timefmt %c`

Format the time using [strftime](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-strftime/) syntax.