# How to force linux to print full path along with timestamp while using find

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find, pwd

I need to store the full path of a specific file found through find (and successive piped operations on find results). I'm using this:

```
find "$PWD" . -iname p_*.raw -printf "%Tc %p\n" | sort  | cut -f 7 -d " "
```

However, as it is it produces shortened file paths `"$PWD"` doesn't seem to have any effect. Is there any way to force it to show full path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recursively list all files with timestamps and full path?](https://superuser.com/questions/228529/how-to-recursively-list-all-files-with-timestamps-and-full-path)

Comment: I might have spaces in the folder names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is close.

You are telling `find` where to look twice, `"$PWD"` and `.`. Drop the second one and add a slash to the first. Add quotes around the name pattern as well.

`find "$PWD/" -iname "p_*.raw" ....`

You might have an issue with the `cut` command as well, since it's only selecting one field rather than name and time. Still, your attempt is almost there.

Comment: This works brilliantly. Although, am not sure what you meant about cut selecting only one field. I do want only one field: the path.

Comment: Only one field for only the path is good. The title included the timestamp. You might also consider placing the `sort` after the `cut`, less work for the sort, and sort by the path rather than the first field which is probably the weekday of the time stamp.

Comment: I kept sort first because I wanted to sort by time modified really. For some reason sort with default options gave me the correct order. If I do cut first, I don't think it'll be able to do that.

Comment: You are correct. `cut` then `sort` would be in order of path, which I thought was your goal. With timestamp order as the goal it is good as it stands. As a caution for future use, the columns are not _always_ that way. When/if it spits out something weird, drop the `cut` and see what the fields are. For example, field 7 for me is the timezone of the timestamp, not path.